# Trying to move header links to footer links by move in default.xml

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying to move the `header.links` (login) to the footer by putting `default.xml` in

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/
```

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <move element="header.links" destination="footer_links" />
</body>
```

I have tried

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf var/generation
var/cache var/page_cache
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/
```

to remove static files and cache and also `setup:upgrade` to update Magento. Is there anything I am doing wrong? The links wont move.

Comment: Which theme you used custom or Luma?

Comment: I have blank as parent, changed header.links to top.links and it worked but now I have bullets instead of a straight list... Haha. Thank Suresh.

Comment: Is it possible to move the links with the "container" so it doesnt break css?